# Operators overloading (+=,=) for own strings

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm trying to create my own class string.
I've got some issues with operator overloading.

**My_string.h**

```
  #include <cstring>
  #include <iostream>
    class My_string
    {
    private:
        char *value;
    public:
        My_string();
        My_string(char *);
        ~My_string();
        My_string operator +=(const My_string&);
        My_string operator =(const My_string&);
        void show()const;
    };
```

**My_string.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "My_string.h"


My_string::My_string()
{
    value = new char[1];
    strcpy(value, "");
}

My_string::My_string(char * r_argument)
{

    value = new char[strlen(r_argument) + 1];
    strcpy(value, r_argument);
}

My_string::~My_string()
{
    delete[]value;
}

My_string My_string::operator+=(const My_string &r_argument)
{
    char * temp_value = new char[strlen(value) + strlen(r_argument.value) + 1];
    strcpy(temp_value, value);
    strcat(temp_value,r_argument.value);
    delete[]value;
    value = new char[strlen(value) + strlen(r_argument.value) + 1];
    strcpy(value, temp_value);
    delete[]temp_value;
    return *this;
}

void My_string::show() const
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

My_string My_string::operator =(const My_string & r_argument)
{
    delete[] value;
    value = new char[strlen(r_argument.value)+1];
    strcpy(value, r_argument.value);
    return *this;
}
```

How to overload +=  and = operators ?They both causes runtime errors. I need all to be in dynamically allocated memory.

Debug Assertion Failed! 
...
Expression: _CrtisValidHeapPointer(block).

Comment: What did you observe when isnpecting your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: What "runtime errors"? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @aleshka-batman  You should show how you use these operators though for example the copy assignment operator is obviously wrong. Also you have to define the copy constructor.

Comment: Your operators `+=` and `=` return *copy* but you don't have your *copy-constructor*

Comment: @Tomáš M 

 Edited.

Comment: Consider using `std::unique_ptr` to make heap management less error-prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator+=` and `operator=` normally return *references* to `this`.

Currently you are returning by value, which is using the compiler-generated copy constructor. That constructor grabs the data buffer pointer `value` which is the root cause of your crash: multiple `delete[]`s on a pointer will not end well!

Start by researching the "Rule Of 3", build your copy constructors and assignment operators, fix the overloaded operator return types, and continue from there.

Comment: "Rule of 3" worked for me. I had to define copy constructor and that's all. It works properly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Lot's more to do here though: e.g. consider `My_string(const char *);`. Do get a good book on C++ to help you in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

At least the copy assignment operator contains a serious bug when an object is assigned to itself because at first it is deleted. Also the operators should return reference to themselves.

Well, the operators can be defined the following way

```
My_string & My_string::operator +=( const My_string &r_argument )
{
    if ( r_argument.value[0] )
    { 
        char *temp_value = new char[strlen(value) + strlen(r_argument.value) + 1];
        strcpy(temp_value, value);
        strcat(temp_value,r_argument.value);

        delete [] value;
        value = temp_value;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

and

```
My_string & My_string::operator =( const My_string &r_argument )
{
    if ( this != &r_argument )
    {
        char *temp_value = value;

        size_t n = strlen( r_argument.value );

        if ( n != strlen( value ) )
        {
            temp_value = new char[ n + 1 ];
        }
        else
        {
            value = nullptr;
        }

        strcpy( temp_value, r_argument.value );

        delete [] value;

        value = temp_value;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Take into account that you need to define explicitly also the copy constructor.